# Overall Code Coverage classes not showing

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I have written apex class but it  is not showing in overall code coverage column  in developer console.
Apex class format :

```
public without sharing class Service {

public class ServiceGet {
public String sourceSystem;
public Customer customer;
public String status;
public BillingAccount billingAccount;}
```

}

I am calling this class in another apex class like Service.ServiceGet().
please help me for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This code cannot be covered because it is not executable. Class and variable declarations never receive code coverage and do not count towards the overall coverage percentage.

See [How do I increase my code coverage, or why can't I cover these lines?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244794/how-do-i-increase-my-code-coverage-or-why-cant-i-cover-these-lines) on Salesforce Stack Exchange for resources on how code coverage is calculated.